# Confusions about python builtin attributes __dict__ and __setattr__

Tags: python

```
class A():
    # A not inherit from object
    pass

a = A()

print 'a.__dict__ : ', a.__dict__  # {}
print 'dir(a) : ', dir(a)  # ['__doc__', '__module__']
print 'dir(A) : ', dir(A)  # ['__doc__', '__module__']
```

1.First question,`a.__dict__`prove that 'a' has attribute `__dict__`,but after dir(a) or dir(A),`__dict__` is not found,where is attr `__dict__`?

```
# next i tried  to give the 'a' attribute 'test' whose value is 1 in 3 diff ways
a.test = 1  # fine!
setattr(a, 'test', 1)  # it works!
a.__setattr__('test', 1)  # Attribute Error raised,'a' has no attr __setattr__
```

2.As I know,`a.test = 1`and`setattr(a, 'test', 1)`actually call `__setattr__`method to set the attribute `test`.But there is no `__setattr__`in dir(a).That's why `a.__setattr__` raise error?Now that how do `a.test`and`setattr(a, 'test', 1)`work?Any advice and suggestions are appreciated,especially the second question,thanks!

Comment: Asuming that `setattr` method can give the instancemethod `__setattr__`?

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir)? In particular, *"it tries to supply an interesting set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set of names"*.

Comment: __ doc__ and __ module__ are contained in A.__dict__, not a.__dict__ .

Comment: Python "special" methods are for advanced users; there are many other more pythonic ways of doing things without make use of them! For furhter infomation, have a look at "Pro Django": http://www.amazon.com/Pro-Django-Experts-Voice-Development/dp/1430258098

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry,I haven't read it.You mean not all built-in attributes included in dir results?just part of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `.__dict__` is a kind of "meta-attribute", it is a storage where normally all attributes are put. As such, it has a special role and that's why it doesn't show up in `dir(...)`.
2. They only call `.__setattr__()` if it exists; if it doesn't, the respective attribute gets just set in `.__dict__`.

Comment: Thank you,for the second question,you meant the attribute just gets set in `__dict__` without `__setattr__`,but how?it doesn't call any method?@glglgl

Comment: @LeoTao No, it is internally built in.

Answer (score 0):

`__setattr__` exists so that you can customize how attributes are set, and similarly with many other "magic" methods. For example, you do not need to define `__new__` or `__init__` in order to be able to make instances of A.